# How to fix ORA-00933 command not properly ended error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
(select DETAIL_ID 
   from OD_TO_SOURCE 
  where OD_SOURCE_ID='S1Mh8trcQL6ggWbt001001') OD_TO_SRC 
  inner join obligation_detail 
     on OD_TO_SRC.OBLIGATION_DETAIL_ID=obligation_detail.detail_id 
  where obligation_detail.record_status = '0' 
    and obligation_detail.obligation_detail_status = '2' 
    and obligation_detail.settlement_date = '20181217'
```

Above sql displays

> ORA-00933 command not properly ended

error. Can anyone let me know what is the issue? Thank you

Comment: I've tagged it more appropriately for you - the ORA tells you it's an Oracle error, not a MySQL error. So the wrong people would have been looking at your question. Take a more careful look at the tags in future so you make sure you are listing your question under the most suitable category. When you're choosing the tags, a description will appear as you select it, or when you hover over it.

Comment: Anyway it looks like your query is incomplete. You've shown us an inner sub-query, and the "join" and "where" clauses of an outer query, but no "select" or "from" sections from the outer query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is what you want to do here:

```
select
    ots.DETAIL_ID
from OD_TO_SOURCE ots
inner join obligation_detail od
    on ots.OBLIGATION_DETAIL_ID = od.detail_id
where
    ots.OD_SOURCE_ID = 'S1Mh8trcQL6ggWbt001001' and
    od.record_status = '0' and
    od.obligation_detail_status = '2' and 
    od.settlement_date = '20181217'
```

It appears that you were trying to join a subquery on the `OD_TO_SOURCE` table to the rest of your query.  But, I see no need for a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you,this query is incomplete where is select statement?

```
select OD_TO_SRC .* from 
(select DETAIL_ID 
   from OD_TO_SOURCE 
  where OD_SOURCE_ID='S1Mh8trcQL6ggWbt001001') OD_TO_SRC 
  inner join obligation_detail 
     on OD_TO_SRC.OBLIGATION_DETAIL_ID=obligation_detail.detail_id 
  where obligation_detail.record_status = '0' 
    and obligation_detail.obligation_detail_status = '2' 
    and obligation_detail.settlement_date = '20181217
```